# "This field is required" when all fields are filled in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

When filling out a form I get "This field is required." even though all fields are filled in.

It doesn't have to do with setting required to False or anything like that, because all fields are required.

views.py

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            username = request.user.get_username()
            category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'],title,username,category)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'main/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

function

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f,title,username,category):
    with open('/uploads/' + category + '/' + title, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

forms.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
        title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
        category = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
        file = forms.FileField()
```

upload.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Upload{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Uploading as: {{ user.username }}
  <form method="post"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The error I get when filling out a form is: "This field is required"

Screenshot:

[image]

When I select a file and it throws the error it unselects whatever file I've selected, similar to how the password field is cleared when hitting sign up without completing every field.

Comment: That's the literal error message: "This field is required"?  With no indication as to what field it is referring to?

Comment: Correct, I can post a screenshot if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file isn't being submitted with the request because you didn't sent the correct `enctype` on the `form` element. Here are [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) concerning that.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

One way to verify this/debug it would be to print the form's data `form.data`, request.POST and/or request.FILES before the call to `is_valid`. Or verifying the request in a browser's dev tools.